# Is there a way to detect the start and end of a pulse train?

Tags: matlab, signals, simulink, digital, pulse

I'm struggling to find a smart way to detect the beginning and end of a pulse train on MATLAB/Simulink. I'm working with real digital signals with unknown and variable periodicity. Can anyone suggest me a smart way to perform this operation and get a decent approximation of the red signal in the figure?
Thanks a lot!

Edit :
I forgot to point out that the operation needs to be performed online.

[image]

Comment: what about diff, with that you will get peaks up and down, then find pediod as items between 2 up pulses,  count how much periods do you have, and last multiply totalTime = `nPeriods*periodDuration`

Comment: it's hard to make this as online operation, but you can rearange the code, to do it. suposing that you are working in a script..

Comment: If the pulse train is anywhere near as perfect as the theoretical image, you could simply track the amplitude. Above threshold for the first time: start of signal. Then just count to see whether the pulse train ended (no more points above threshold) or continues (amplitude below threshold, then back above)

Comment: Is your pulse train a regular/fixed length? Many serial comms methods will hold the line high until they are ready to send the signal when the signal will fall low for 1 cycle before the data is sent.